# Is the word territory the same as a country or a nation?

Tags: word-usage

I heard about the word territory in ancient Greece or The New Territories in Hong Kong. Is the word territory the same as a country or a nation? Could I said The USA is a territory or the UK is a territory?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. As a rule, Stack Exchange expects you to attempt some initial research; a dictionary will tell you *territory* is an area of land, but it has additional uses and more specific definitions depending on context. I strongly encourage you to take thet site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score -1):

No. You could not say that the United States is a territory. It is a country. You could also not say that the UK is a territory (it is also a country.) However, a place like Guam would be considered a territory of the United states. In general, a territory is something, that, according to Merriam-Webster:

> A geographic area belonging to or under the jurisdiction of a governmental authority

Which also answers your other question, by showing how territories are not the same as countries, because some countries have territories that belong to them, but the territories themselves are not countries.

In addition, here is the link to my source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/territory

Comment: You are conflating the political sense of *territory* with its more general use for a geographic region; you can find legitimate examples of *Britain is a territory* or *Spain is a territory* and so on and so forth.

Comment: Thank you, Mr Joe Kerr. :D